# Why is my code changing the labeling for my legend?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, legend, color

By default, the legend that is created from a layout includes a label with the field name. However, when I run my Python script to change the symbology of a layer, the label is changed to include the source that the field name is coming from. Any idea why this could be happening or how to stop it?

Picture below shows the legend with the extended label even though the field is just called "-1*TE_samples".

[image]

The code below is what I used to change the symbology of my maps.

```
# define project
#project_path = r"C:\Users\person\Desktop\folder\project.aprx" #you can ignor this line if you use "CURRENT" like below
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

# specify map in project named "Map"
m = p.listMaps('Geogenics_revised')[0]

#changing the break type and colorramp of the symbology of every layer in a map
for lyr in m.listLayers():
    if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
        sym = lyr.symbology
        sym.updateRenderer('GraduatedColorsRenderer')
        sym.renderer.classificationMethod = 'NaturalBreaks'
        sym.renderer.breakCount = 4
        sym.renderer.colorRamp = arcpy.mp.ColorRamp('Blues (Continuous)')
        # this bottom portion of the code goes through every class break and rounds the upper value and label
        # the label works by splitting the original string output into floats in a list, rounding the float numbers,
        # and then recombining the floats into a string
        count = 0
        for brk in sym.renderer.classBreaks:
            brk.upperBound = round(brk.upperBound, 2) #label for upper boundary is rounded to 2 decimals
            print(brk.upperBound)
            labellist = []
            labelsplit = brk.label.split(" - ") 
            for num in labelsplit:
                num = round(float(num), 2) # rounded to 2 decimals
                num = str(num)
                labellist.append(num)
            if len(labellist) == 2:   # only runs this if label consists of two numbers 
                brk.label = labellist[0]+" - "+labellist[1] #label for text range
            count += 1
        lyr.symbology = sym
```

Comment: Probably not the cause, but it's generally bad practice to start field names with special characters or numbers.

Comment: You could have discovered a bug, that when a field is named with specials characters (especially -1) the source is concatenated. Have you tried naming the field without special characters?

Comment: @enolan sorry about the late reply but the problem persists even when removing the special characters